# Effectively dealing with people who are immune to criticism

Tags: discussion, etiquette

While browsing the site today I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970753/880984). Since the php and javascript tags are such a jungle, a lot of questioners need more guidance than simply "use this code instead, it will do what you want". So I made a comment about code only answers being not very good (because I thought in this case specifically it warranted more explanation). The comment thread quickly escalated:

[image]

I am still a little dumbstruck, and I am wondering how I (specifically in this case) could have handled the exchange better. Should I just walk away or what? Downvote and forget? I am having trouble deciding when was the point I should have just stopped responding. Was I too aggressive? I feel like I don't often get overly negative responses to my comments, so I am honestly confused.

Comment: That comment thread... went downhill quickly. Honestly; I would downvote and leave after the first response.

Comment: As someone who is immune to criticism, I'd suggest letting it go.  Also, takes two to tango.

Comment: Personally, I feel your first two comments were okay, but when you start a comment with "No need to be a jerk", you are going to have an escalation.

Comment: I pasted a screenshot of the comments so we'd have something to reference. I also nuked the comment thread because the comments I left in that thread address everything that was brought up.

Comment: @TimSeguine a good way to tell whether you should just bail out of a thread is to read your post in Mr. Rogers' voice. If it sounds unlike Mr. Rogers, you probably shouldn't say it. Conversation would probably have ended before your 2nd post. He loses out on a potential helper, and you lose out on nothing.

Comment: @Compass thanks, neighbor. I'll use that.

Comment: What I find amusing, if he had put 'Try this, [code]' as so many do or other fluff text it would have not been discussed.

Comment: @Stacker-flow I probably would have still commented, although I can't say for certain.

Comment: title of the question could be "Effectively dealing with 99.99% people"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as what you said, the statement `No need to be a jerk.` seems mildly inappropriate in context.  Him saying that he doesn't feel that your criticism is valid is not him being a jerk.  He actually responded rather constructively to that unconstructive statement (and continued to stay rather constructive for the rest of the comment thread).

All in all I see a few comments/portions of comments getting a bit noisy, but they do seem to be staying constructive.

What I'm really seeing is someone who simply doesn't agree with your position on a subjective topic, and who isn't particularly interested in discussing it with you.  While I may disagree with his position on said subjective topic, I see nothing wrong in how he responded to your criticism, given his position.

Since he clearly has no interest in discussing this with you I'd say you're largely wasting your time by commenting past the second or third comment, but it's your time to waste if you want to waste it.

Comment: *"but it's your time to waste if you want to waste it"* - Except that you should not be filling up the comment section with debates like this; it is irrelevant to the question.  After the second or third comment, you should open a chat session with the guy if you must continue the discussion (and the guy likewise wants to continue).

Comment: Okay what got me going I think was "your opinion is unfounded". I can admit that made me see red. He doesn't know me, but somehow knows that my opinions have no factual basis? Screw that.

Comment: @iCodez Sure, you can move it to chat if you want, but fundamentally comments are there to critique posts and to discuss how they can be improved, which is what this is.

Comment: @TimSeguine At the time he made that quote you had stated an opinion without providing any basis for it.  While the statement might have been a bit excessive, it was at least correct at the time that you hasn't provided a foundation for your opinion.  Try to always read things in as constructive of a light as you can.  Whether that's the true intention or not, you're better off.

Comment: @Servy I don't want to argue semantics, because I think that is a valid point anyway (assume good faith and all), but "unfounded" means that something *has no* foundation, not that none was presented.

Answer (score 14):

Do not engage.

Once a user has responded to your comment (especially on the internet), it's rare that you'll change their mind.

In this case, a competing answer that does fully explain the code would be a better choice. It'd serve the purpose you want to serve (educate the OP) and it would allow other users to see what a good answer looks like. Be the change you wish to see, and all that.

As always, if there are comment flags that devolve into being not-constructive, it's probably best to flag the whole thread and move on. A moderator will see it and intervene if necessary.

Comment: I have an opinion and the OP has an opinion. We disagree in our opinions. I don't care if I get downvoted but honestly to bring it here? I know my opinion is against the majority. This is doing nothing at all but causing controversy. I'd say that's even less constructive than my code-only answers. Why can't anyone just agree to disagree.

Comment: In this case both users' comments were quite constructive, as far as I can see.  I see no reason to discourage a civil discussion about a topic.  Sometimes people's positions will change (whether it be yours or theirs), sometimes they won't.  Sometimes useful information comes out of the discussion even if positions don't change.  Yes, as soon as either side devolves into unconstructive discussions or insults, walk away, but when someone is responding constructively and merely asserting a position you disagree with refusing to engage is not the proper response at all.

Comment: @JonathanGray To be fair, the OP here was mainly trying to make sure they weren't being too aggressive: _"...and I am wondering how I (specifically in this case) could have handled the exchange better."_ So it's not quite that they are bringing your disagreement here, but that they wanted feedback to ensure they are handling discussions correctly. Additionally, though I disagree with your stance on code-only answers, as Servy has said, you did stay rather civil and constructive, so kudos to that.

Comment: @JonathanGray There are some people who think Code only answers aren't good answers. Some think they're OK. I think it's contextual. I'm solely responding to the "What to do if the person I'm having a discussion with isn't responding to criticism" part.  We could blank out everyone's names involved and it'd still be the same answer.  So, to recap: I'm discussing the general advice I give; I don't back any particular person in this scenario. I'd say the same to you if you had asked the meta question instead of the the other person.

Comment: This is obviously a correct answer, but I marked the other answer accepted because I think it helped me more concretely.